# Windows SMTP Relay based on Office 365 user account

Tags: office365, smtp, iis-6

I am trying to setup a SMTP service on Windows Server (IIS). I have followed the instruction from [Microsoft's docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-configure-iis-for-relay-with-office-365#set-up-exchange-online-as-an-smtp-relay-using-windows-server-2012) but unfortunatelly emails cannot be sent.
I have created the mailbox *no-reply@mydomain.com* (Office 365) and I have used its credentials to configure SMTP service. When I try to send email through my SMTP server, I get following Delivery Status Notification which is placed in *Badmail* directory:

```
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;553 5.7.1 We don't relay mail
```

I have tried a lot of different email messages but one of them is the simpliest:

```
FROM: no-reply@mydomain.com
TO: my-account@gmail.com
SUBJECT: Test email

Some Text
```

Furthermore, I have configured *Domains* section:

```
mail.mydomain.com - Local (Default)
*.com - Remote
*.eu  - Remote
test.mydomain.com - Local (Alias)
```

How can I make the SMTP service send emails using Office 365 account?

Comment: Have you followed [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3) document and configured the SMTP service according to which option you want to use?  It sounds like you’re trying to do option #1 which will not allow you to send from anybody@yourdomain.com.

Comment: I've read mentioned document and as far as I understand I should configure a connector to send mail using SMTP relay (Option #3). Nevertheless, I don't understand why it isn't possible to send emails basing on configuration which is mentioned in [Option 1 - TLS and other encryption options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3#tls-and-other-encryption-options) - the same which I used in the first place.

Comment: It looks like the SMTP service is not authenticating. You will setup the SMTP service with a smarthost and configure it to the office 365 settings in the document. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303734/how-to-configure-the-smtp-virtual-server-for-message-delivery#6

Comment: As far as I understand, mentioned document contains configuration which is consistent with the one presented in my question. Nevertheless, I think you're right - there is a problem with the authentication. After I had changed the outbound TCP port to 25, it worked as intendend (almost, because it didn't send emails to _mydomain.com_). Eventually, I have changed the SMTP relay service provider and it works properly even with TCP port 587.